# What is the Avatamsaka Sutra about?

Tags: mahayana, sutras, texts

I'm not really expecting a short summary, but I'd be happy to get one. This is a 1600 page sutra in English (and cost over $100 on Amazon). It gets reference a lot in the Brahma Net Sutra and Huayan Buddhism.

Given that, what is the best way to dig into this... is there a Cliff Notes version?

And what is the Avatamsaka Sutra prescribing its readers to do?

Comment: I thought you may enjoy this article.  I just came across it 10 minutes ago. "The Avatamsaka Sutra in art" http://www.tricycle.com/feature/reflections-flowerbank-world

Answer (score 8, accepted):

During the beginning of the 4th century CE, Buddhist scholars began composing a new series of Sūtras with the purpose of synthesizing and organizing concepts from earlier Mahāyāna Sūtras, a task which the authors viewed as the *third turning of the wheel of Dharma*.  Three Sūtras from this period left a major impact on the intellectual endeavor of Mahāyāna monastics: the *Avatamsaka Sūtra*, the *Lankāvatāra Sūtra*, and the *Sandhinirmocana Sūtra*.  The underline theme found in these three Sūtras, including the *Avatamsaka Sūtra* is the experience of the universe formed by consciousness detailed within epic narratives.[1](http://www.tofugu.com/2014/02/06/the-real-japanese-monks-guide-to-buddhism-in-japan/)

The *Avatamsaka Sūtra* is also know for expounding the  teaching about the ever-abiding Buddha-nature that constitutes ultimate reality.[2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DU88MWC)  However, some scholars believe the *Avatamska Sūtra* was composed earlier between 200 BC and 200 CE and played a major formative role in the development of  Buddhist thought.[3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DU88MWC)   Nonetheless the Sūtra played an important role in the formation of Mahāyāna Buddhist teachings, which cannot be down played.

> "The *Avatamsaka Sūtra* or *Flower Garland Sūtra* was translated into
>   Chinese by Buddhabhadra between 408 and 410 CE.  It gives a very
>   detailed account of Shakyamuni/Vairochana’s quest for enlightenment,
>   and offers the view that existence is the combination of individual
>   identity and interdependence, a crucial theme in the development of
>   Indian Buddhist thought.  The *Avatamsaka Sūtra* became influential in
>   the late sixth and seventh centuries through the works of monks such
>   as Fashun (557-649 CE) and Zhiyen (602-668 CE), and later was the
>   central text of the semi-esoteric Huayen order in China, which is
>   known as [Kegon in Japan](http://www.tofugu.com/2014/02/06/the-real-japanese-monks-guide-to-buddhism-in-japan/).”[4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1585678503)

The mandala principle found in the *Avatamasak Sūtra*, “conveys the most extraordinary visions that engage the audience in creating a setting and developing a receptivity that makes it possible for them to receive the Universal Vehicle teaching of the profound freedom and magnificent destiny of all living beings.” [5](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1585678503)

> An example of this found in the *Avatamsaka Sūtra*,  "the Buddha is
>   surrounded by an enormous host of visitors, many from other universes,
>   who sit in flower towers thousands of miles high, flown at more than
>   warp speed across the reaches of space from worlds beyond as many
>   worlds as there are grains of sand in sixty-two Ganges riverbeds.  The
>   towers are arranged in the cardinal directions, intermediate quarters,
>   and at the zenith and nadir in a classical mandala formation.  During
>   the teaching, Shakyamuni Buddha now and then transforms himself into
>   the sapphire-blue Vairochana, radiating magic light rays from his
>   forehead that temporarily bestow on each member of the audience the
>   intensely accelerated vision of all their past life experiences and
>   all their future life attainments, up to and including attainment of
>   perfect buddhahood in a future universe and performance of buddha
>   deeds for the sake of all beings.  At the end of the teaching, the
>   Bodhisattva Maitreya introduces the hero of the tale, the
>   pilgrim-seeker Sudhana, a banker’s son, into the magical tower of
>   Vairochana.  There Sudhana beholds the entire evolutionary history of
>   Maitreya from a self-centered, unenlightened being to a functioning
>   buddha.
>
> At the same time, the panorama unfolds in infinite resonant variations
>   in every atom of the universe, each containing infinite
>   micro-universes, which contain infinite worlds where infinite living
>   Sudhanas enter infinite Vairochana towers and behold infinite
>   evolutionary panoramas of infinite living Maitreyas.”[6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1585678503)

The *Avatamasak Sūtra* utilizes a narrative mandala principle for the reader, in which Buddha transports his audience into a new dimension of consciousness exploring the potentialities of their possible destiny.

1. [The Buddhist Religion: A Historical Introduction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DU88MWC) page 91
2. [The Buddhist Religion: A Historical Introduction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DU88MWC) page 182
3. [Manadala The Architecture of Enlightenment](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1585678503) page 32
4. [Manadala The Architecture of Enlightenment](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1585678503) page 23
5. [Manadala The Architecture of Enlightenment](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1585678503) page 135
6. [Manadala The Architecture of Enlightenment](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1585678503) page 135

Comment: Whenever I read such texts with diamond trees and so many other celestial beings I wonder what is sought to be conveyed. I feel like somehow complete the reading of that part as a ritual. Is that not unnecessary part?

Answer (score 1):

According to a page on About.com ...

"The Avatamsaka Sutra is a Mahayana Buddhist scripture that reveals how reality appears to an enlightened being. It is best known for its sumptuous descriptions of the inter-existence of all phenomena."

The content:
http://www.cttbusa.org/fas1/fas_contents.asp

The cliff note version (?):
http://www.buddhism.org/Sutras/2/Avatamsaka_Sutra.htm

Not sure this is what you are looking for though. Good luck.

Comment: @medhini, http://www.cttbusa.org/fas1/fas_contents.asp is not complete. Some chapters are not linked to.

Comment: @medhini, I'm afraid I can't award the bounty because SE wants me to wait 8 hours but my account will cancelled in 1 hour.  Sorry about that.